# Scale ModelInstance and it's animations in libgdx

Tags: animation, model, libgdx

I have ran into some problems with animated models. I load a model, create a modelinstance, which I then scale like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < modelInstance.nodes.size; i++) {
        modelInstance.nodes.get(i).scale.set(axisScale);
    }
    modelInstance.calculateTransforms();
```

(Then I create a bullet shape matching the modelinstance bounding box)
This has been working great so far. But now I got some new animated models and as soon as they start to animate they revert to the original scale that they were exported to from Maya (which is a factor 100 wrong for my game).

Is there something wrong with the model or the fbx-export or am I doing something wrong? I tried to scale all NodeKeyFrames in the top NodeAnimations, but still can not get it to look good (model is translated when it starts to animate)

I have looked in a G3DJ file for the model, but I am not sure how it should look. I see the the "bones" still have scale set to 1.0 but all the "top-nodes" got the correct scale 0.01

```
"nodes": [
    {
        "id": "chest_small", 
        "scale": [ 0.010000,  0.010000,  0.010000], 
        "parts": [
            {
                "meshpartid": "shape1_part1", 
                "materialid": "smallchest", 
                "bones": [
                    {
                        "node": "chest_medium1:root", 
                        "translation": [-0.000000, -0.000000, -0.000000,  0.000000], 
                        "rotation": [-0.000000,  0.000000, -0.000000,  1.000000], 
                        "scale": [ 1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000]
                    }, 
                    {
                        "node": "chest_medium1:chest", 
                        "translation": [-0.000000,  19.035118, -0.000000,  0.000000], 
                        "rotation": [-0.000000,  0.000000, -0.000000,  1.000000], 
                        "scale": [ 1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000]
                    }
                ], 
                "uvMapping": [[  0]]
            }
        ], 
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "lid", 
                "parts": [
                    {
                        "meshpartid": "shape2_part1", 
                        "materialid": "smallchest", 
                        "bones": [
                            {
                                "node": "chest_medium1:hinges", 
                                "translation": [-0.000000,  19.035118, -13.654591,  0.000000], 
                                "rotation": [-0.000000,  0.000000, -0.000000,  1.000000], 
                                "scale": [ 1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000]
                            }, 
                            {
                                "node": "chest_medium1:lid", 
                                "translation": [-0.000000,  29.616650,  2.217263,  0.000000], 
                                "rotation": [-0.000000,  0.000000, -0.000000,  1.000000], 
                                "scale": [ 1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000]
                            }
                        ], 
                        "uvMapping": [[  0]]
                    }
                ]
            },
```

Comment: Scale in your modelling application and bake the scale before exporting. Scaling in your game is almost never a good solution.

Comment: Yes. I would if I could. Got the models from 3rd part and I can not start to fix this in maya even. I spent whole day trying to scale the model in maya, but its locked and inherits transforms and bone scale etc etc. Its way too complicated for someone with zero training in 3d modelling. I also get a warning when exporting about a animation tangent.. I have other animated models. Character models with animations and they work fine. So I am guessing there is something with these new models

Comment: Could you give short explaiation why scaling in code is bad idea? I never scale during game play, only once when loading the assets